# Is there another way to to .load?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

The result of load is not used - is the message that appears on my screen. is there another way to resolve this?

Tried using stack overflow but nobody has had a similar issue and need the code completed by Monday Deadline.

```
 private void loadUserInformation() {

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
   if (user != null) {
       if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
           Glide.with(this)
                   .load(user.getPhotoUrl().toString())
                   .load(imageView);
       }
       if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
            editText.setText(user.getDisplayName());
       }
   }
}
```

expected output to be loading the image in imageview so that it is saved to the account logged in.

Actual output - it does not do this and does not load the image as a result.

Comment: version android studio 3.3.2

Comment: Could you please tell us what user.getPhotoUrl().toString() returns? And if the if which encompasses the Glide call is called?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the explanation of [how to use glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) I think that you need to change this line :
 `.load(imageView);`

To this:

`.into(imageView);`

From the github page of glide:

`Glide.with(this).load("image link").into(imageView);`

So I think that you were only missing the last part.